# /usr/bin/w cuts long lines when redirected to file or pipe

Tags: bash

when I run "/usr/bin/w" on my terminal, I see the long lines, such as

```
user    pts/0    :0.0             08Jan13  2:48m  6.02s 12:36  gnome-terminal --maximize
```

however, when I redirect to file or pipe, such as  "/usr/bin/w | cat", the lines are truncated to length of 80

```
user    pts/0    :0.0             08Jan13  2:53m  6.02s 12:36  gnome-termi
```

Is it possible to get long lines even when redirecting to pipe ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TIME TO INVOKE FOSS SUPERHERO POWERS!

Inspecting the source code for `w.c` learns:

```
if (ioctl(STDOUT_FILENO, TIOCGWINSZ, &win) != -1 && win.ws_col > 0)
    maxcmd = win.ws_col;
else if ((p = getenv("COLUMNS")))
    maxcmd = atoi(p);
else
    maxcmd = 80;
if (maxcmd < 71)
    xerrx(EXIT_FAILURE, _("%d column window is too narrow"), maxcmd);

maxcmd -= 21 + userlen + (from ? fromlen : 0) + (longform ? 20 : 0);
if (maxcmd < 3)
    xwarnx(_("warning: screen width %d suboptimal"), win.ws_col);
```

So

```
export COLUMNS=300
```

should be enough, or

```
COLUMNS=300 /usr/bin/w | cat
```

to test :)

Comment: I would use the second form, to avoid confusing any future programs that check the value of `COLUMNS`.

Comment: i did not understand the method

Comment: @user2713461 what about it do you not understand? My joke about "SUPERHERO POWERS"? Or something else? _(The joke just means: "because this is open source, we can answer the question by looking at the code")_

Comment: what is export COLUMNS = 300?? where should we do it?

Comment: It's telling the shell to put a variable in the environment for any child processes it runs. As you can see, the source of `w` uses `getenv("COLUMNS")` to determine terminal width, so you can just override it (second form overrides it for a single command). Any POSIX shell will do this (sh, bash, ksh etc.)